# How to consolidate angularjs templates and controllers in a CRUD config

Tags: angularjs

I have a web app that provide restful api on several tables from the backend to the angularjs front end.

The api is simply CRUD functions. So far I have the same actions for three tables. They are: list, show detail, crate new, and edit.

It is simple to implement in angular, all I need to do is to create a controller and a view template for each action.

However, the problem is for each table, I have to duplicate the almost same controllers and view templates. They are identical in business logic, but different in object name, and a few functions unique to the table.

Is there a way to consolidate the controllers and html templates while still have the capability to insert some specific functions into the controller depends on which table/action it is controlling?

#### Edit

For example two tables: school and student. Both of them have property `name` and `address`. Student has a special function `graduate`.

For school, I can have a controller js file like this (example code won't run):

```js
angular.module('school', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/schools', {
      controller:'SchoolListController as ctrl',
      templateUrl:'school/schoollist.html'
    })
    .when('/schools/:id', {
      controller:'SchoolDetailController as ctrl',
      templateUrl:'school/schooldetail.html'
    })
    .when('/schools/edit/:id', {
      controller: 'SchoolEditController as ctrl',
      templateUrl: 'school/schooledit.html'
    })

}])

.controller('SchoolListController', function($scope,$location, Models) {
  var ctrl = this
  var schools = Models.School.query(function () {
    ctrl.schools = schools
  })
})

.controller('SchoolDetailController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Models) {
  var ctrl = this
  var school = Models.School.get({ id: $routeParams.id }, function () {
    ctrl.school = school
  })

  ctrl.delete = function(){
    // code to delte
  }
})

.controller('SchoolEditController', function(Models, $routeParams, $location) {
  var ctrl = this;
  var school = Models.School.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(){
      ctrl.school = school
    })
 
   ctrl.save = function(){
    ctrl.school.$save()
  }
  ctrl.cancel = function() {
    //
  }
})
```

For student, the exactly same js file needs to be written again, but just change the name from `school` to `student`, except that I need to add a `ctrl.graduate` in student's detail controller.

I can create a generating function `generateController(objName)` to generate the controller according to provided `objName`, however, I cannot **later** add `graduate` to student's controller.

For html template

School and student both share the same format of template (or at least a large chunk of the view). E.g. the list view, both of them are a table, with Name and Address as columns. And clicking the row of the column will show the detail view.

Again, I need to create two sets of identical template files for school and student, with a few difference.

So what is the best way to consolidate the duplications in both controller and templates?

Comment: A small example of what you are trying to do would be useful.

Comment: @Matsemann Just added an example